# An equivalent for ubiquityIdentityToken under OSX 10.7

Tags: ios, icloud, nsfilemanager

I'm trying to add iCloud support to my iOS-5.1 application, according to [Apple's iCloud Design Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iCloudDesignGuide/Chapters/iCloudFundametals.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012094-CH6-SW13) at section "Prepare Your App to Use iCloud".
It says:

> Early in your app launch process—in the application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (iOS) or applicationDidFinishLaunching: method (OS X), check for iCloud availability by calling the NSFileManager method ubiquityIdentityToken, as follows:

`id currentiCloudToken = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] ubiquityIdentityToken];`

The problem is, this method (`ubiquityIdentityToken`) is available in OS X v10.8 and later, and I have only 10.7.4 installed.

Is there any workaround, or other solution, if I do development under 10.7 ? 
And why is this method availability tied to OSX version, and not to iOS version?

Answer (score 5):

Andrea's answer covers your first question.

Regarding your second question on why that seems to be the case: according to the *iOS* [NSFileManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class documentation, the `ubiquityIdentityToken` is only available for iOS 6.0+. You may have been reading the OS X write-up for `NSFileManager` instead of the iOS one, so you saw the OS X requirements instead.

Answer (score 1):

From the OS X Release Notes:

> In Mac OS 10.7, the only way to check whether the user is logged into
>   iCloud with Data & Documents enabled is to invoke *-[NSFileManager
>   URLForUbiquityContainerIdentifier:]* and check for a non-nil URL.
>   However this method can sometimes block for a significant amount of
>   time, making it unsuitable for calling from the main thread.